# How to fix Ban command not working Discord.js v12?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The ping command works, but when I try to use the ban command, it doesn't do anything. It won't even log to the console. I've tried discord.js@12.5.3 and discord.js@12.3.1. I've also tried running my code on another computer and it still won't work.

Here is my code:

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();



client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content === '!ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
 } else if (message.content === '!getBanned') {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();

        if (!member) {
            console.log('member not found');
        } else {
            member.ban();
        }
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in the part of the code where you check if the `message.content` equals '!getBanned', you used the equal operator, `===`. So now the entire content of the message has to be exactly `!getBanned`, so when you use, e.g. `!getBanned @Wumpus`, the content of the message isn't equal. There are many ways to fix this, but for now you should just go with the [`string.startsWith()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) function:

```
if (message.content.startsWith("!getBanned") {
    // put all the code that gets the member mention and bans the member here
}
```